# Tool to inspect Python objects without changing them

Tags: python

While trying to track down a resource leak in a Python program this evening, it occurred to me that modern ORMs make the job quite difficult. An object which is, in fact, sitting alone in memory with no children will suddenly appear to have a dozen associated objects as you start checking its attributes because, of course, each attribute dereference invokes a descriptor that pulls in additional information on-the-fly.

I even noticed that doing a simple `print` of one particular object wound up doing a database query and pulling more linked objects into memory — ruining the careful reference counts that I had been computing — because its `__repr__()` built the displayed name out of a few associated objects.

There are, it happens, a few techniques that allow objects to be inspected *without* affecting them — operations like `type(obj)` and `id(obj)` and `obj.__dict__`. (But not *printing* the `__dict__`, since that invokes `__repr__()` on every single value in the dictionary!) **Has anyone ever combined these few “safe” inspection methods** to support, at a prompt like the Python debugger, convenient inspection and exploration of a Python object graph so that I can see where these files are being held open, running me out of file descriptors?

I need, essentially, an anti-Heisenberg tool, that prevents my acts of inspection from having any side effects!

**The “inspect” module:**

One answer suggests that I try the `inspect()` module, but it looks like it dereferences every attribute on the object you supply:

```
import inspect
class Thing(object):
    @property
    def one(self):
        print 'one() got called!'
        return 1
t = Thing()
inspect.getmembers(t)
```

This outputs:

```
one() got called!
[('__class__', <class '__main__.Thing'>),
 ('__delattr__', <method-wrapper '__delattr__'…),
 …
 ('one', 1)]
```

Comment: Perhaps you might show an example of what output you would actually like to see?

Comment: could you find an acceptable solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.2 now provides `inspect.getattr_static()` for precisely this kind of use case:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/inspect#fetching-attributes-statically

The source code link from the top of the docs page should make it fairly easy to backport that functionality to earlier versions (although keep in mind that as 3.x stdlib code, it isn't built to handle old-style classes).

I'm not aware of any existing tools that combine that kind of technique with inspection of `obj.__dict__` to navigate a whole object graph without invoking descriptors, though.

Comment: This code actually does a few things that are not necessary in my case: it inspects descriptors so that it can report the names of attributes that are generated as properties. But in my case — wanting to know what objects are keeping which other objects are in existence — I actually want virtual attributes like properties to disappear, because, by definition, they can't affect any reference counts unless you invoke them. I just want to know which associated objects actually have elevated reference counts — which, I think, will drive towards manual inspection of ``__dict__``.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how *safe* the various methods are (it seems fairly dependent on your particular situation) but the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/inspect.html) module provides a tremendous number of inspection tools.

Comment: An interesting idea! But the main function supported by `inspect`, the `getmembers()` call, seems to invoke every descriptor on a given object — take a look at the example that I have appended to my question.

Comment: @BrandonCraigRhodes Yep, I couldn't find any way around that in 2.x, at least things look up in Python 3.x. You mention wanting to be able to "see where these files are being held open, running me out of file descriptors?". You are familiar with [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) right? You could do `lsof | grep python` to see which files it's holding open. If you have some control over their names, you could use that to give yourself some indication of what's holding them open...